# web cam stops again and again after once code is run in ubuntu opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

I want to capture images from webcam and then further do image processing for ANPR (Automatic number plate Recognition) in python 2.7 using opencv 2.4.10 in Ubuntu 14.04. When I run this simple code, it detects my camera once and then camera stops working.
Code is:

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
s, img = cam.read()
winName = "Movement Indicator"
cv2.namedWindow(winName, cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
while s:
  cv2.imshow( winName,img )
  s, img = cam.read()
  key = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF
  if key == 27:
    cv2.destroyWindow(winName)
    break
print "Goodbye"
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. I was not releasing cam. It works fine now